# Skinning of TOpenDialog and TOpenPictureDialog with VCL styles

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles

Is it possible to skin the TOpenDialog and the TOpenPictureDialog with VCL syles?

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is No, currently using Delphi XE2 or XE3 is not possible apply directly the Vcl Styles to a non VCL form (or to forms created outside of a VCL Application).

Now the long answer,  is technically possible apply the Vcl Styles to these kind of dialogs, but this require a lot of work (believe me is a lot of work).

The key is using a [WH_CBT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_cbthook) Hook, detecting the `HCBT_CREATEWND` code and then checking if the class of the window is [`#32770`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (the class for a dialog box.) from here you can replace the *window procedure* using the [`SetWindowLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the `GWL_WNDPROC` index.

That was the easy part, now which you have the control of the messages sent by the windows dialog 
you must iterate over the child controls and replace the  *window procedure* again using the
GWL_WNDPROC index. This can be done creating Wrapper class (this is the hard work) for each control used in a windows dialog (button, syslistview32, Combobox and so on)

This a sample of definition for a Wrapper class for the `syslistview32` windows class.

```
  TListViewWnd = class(TCustomListView)
  private
    FNewWndProc  : Pointer;
    FOrgWndProc  : Pointer;
    Fhwnd: THandle;
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure DestroyWnd; override;
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  public
    constructor Create(hwnd: THandle);
    destructor  Destroy;override;
  end;
```

Finally you can use the already existing VCL Styles hooks defined for the Vcl Controls like the TListView on this way

```
TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TListViewWnd, TListViewStyleHook);
```

I' ve already done part of the tasks described above, but is not finished yet, due which this kind of project require a lot of time.

[image]

Comment: Looks nice! (except those make by yourself details :-) [+1]

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, yes because there is not way to hack the undocumented `DirectUIHWND` :(

Answer (score 4):

For any interested the [`VCL Styles Utils Project`](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/) now supports dialogs

[image]

You can find more information about this feature on [this blog post](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/the-vcl-styles-utils-project-now-supports-dialogs-and-popup-menus/).